# CSS span padding & background in h1

Tags: css

I'm using an H1 tag for title text and a SPAN tag inside it in order to add background color and padding, as per example:

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xqd87/86/)

The problem is when the text overflows onto another line, the SPAN element padding does not effect the text on the other line/s.

Any one have any ideas about how to fix please? (i have looked at/tried the other examples here but ran into issues when using the 'border-left' technique - renders differently across ALL browsers.) Is there a way using jquery? Cheers, S.

**EDIT:**

Think I've managed to get this working ok - see http://jsfiddle.net/xqd87/124/

Comment: Why not add the background colour and padding directly to the `<h1>`? You should try to use as little HTML as possible.

Comment: thanks but display:block makes the background cover the whole text area - I only want it to surround the text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, the best I can do is add `white-space:pre-wrap;` to `.bg-box`. This gives you the desired space to the right of line ends but unfortunately doesn't add space to the left of a new line.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xqd87/96/)

Answer (score 0):

just add `display: block;` to `.box-bg`: http://jsfiddle.net/xqd87/87/

at least, i don't understand why you're needing the span - the same thing can be achived just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xqd87/88/

Comment: thanks but display:block makes the background cover the whole text area - I only want it to surround the text!

Answer (score 0):

Padding of inline elements will add space in the start and the end of the text inside element. If you want to add padding of the block element, make it `display:block`

Comment: thanks but display:block makes the background cover the whole text area - I only want it to surround the text!

Answer (score 0):

write `display:block` in your `span` tag because `span` is an `inline element` which not add `vertical padding` in there `width`.

That's why the next line not considered his `padding`

Comment: thanks but display:block makes the background cover the whole text area - I only want it to surround the text!

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally.

Here is my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/AAyNq/

The word-spacing is controlled by the negative text-indent. The jQuery will take care of the first word of the scentence (see the padding-left in the jQuery)